# Failed to run a Shiny app on AWS Ubuntu instance. xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://127.0.0.1:3572'

Tags: r, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I tried to run a shiny app that runs perfectly on my local Mac. I sent all files to ubuntu instance of AWS under /srv/shiny-server. I tried to launch it in R by :

> library(shiny)
>
> runApp()

and got this error:

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3572

/usr/bin/xdg-open: 771: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found

/usr/bin/xdg-open: 771: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found

/usr/bin/xdg-open: 771: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found

/usr/bin/xdg-open: 771: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found

/usr/bin/xdg-open: 771: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found

/usr/bin/xdg-open: 771: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found

xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://127.0.0.1:3572'

Looks like it's some system files. I haven't seen anything related to system files like this. Any idea how to deal with  it?

Comment: Hey, I'm running into the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
runApp(launch.browser = FALSE)
```

With this parameter Shiny will not launch browser on the host machine.